# Flutter ListView is not visible or hidden

Tags: android, flutter, dart

## I am trying to make ListView for my app. when I add listview, listview is not visible or showing.

### INFO

Flutter version: 3.3.8
Engine revision 857bd6b74c
Dart version 2.18.4
DevTools version 2.15.0

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 50),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: const DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage("..."),
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
                                ),
                              ),
                              const Text("Pineapple")
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: No error shown somehow?

Comment: Why the ListView is in a Column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove unnecessary widgets like `Expanded()`, `Column()`, etc. You don't need to use those widgets cause you use `ListView()`, `ListView()` itself takes multiple children. So you won't need to use `Column()` or `Expanded()` inside of `ListView()`. Here is the full solution

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 50),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 200,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: const DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"),
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                        ),
                        const Text("Pineapple")
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add property "primary: false"**

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
body: Container(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 50),
child: Column(
children: [
Container(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
child: Column(
children: [
Expanded(
child: ListView(
shrinkWrap: true,
primary:false,
children: [
Expanded(
child: Column(
children: [
Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
image: const DecorationImage(
image: NetworkImage("..."),
),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
),
),
const Text("Pineapple")
],
),
)
],
),
)
],
),
)
],
)
)
);
}

Answer (score 0):

**Just Remove Expand() Widget**

return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
body: Container(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 50),
child: Column(
children: [
Container(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
child: Column(
children: [
ListView(
shrinkWrap: true,
primary: false,
children: [
Column(
children: [
Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
image: const DecorationImage(
image: NetworkImage("..."),
),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
),
const Text("Pineapple")
],
)
],
)
],
),
)
],
)));

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Expanded` Widgets

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
  return Scaffold( 
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100], 
    body: Container( 
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 50), 
      child: Column( 
        children: [ 
          Container( 
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0), 
            child: Column( 
              children: [ 
                ListView( 
                  shrinkWrap: true, 
                  primary:false, 
                  children: [ 
                    Column( 
                      children: [ 
                        Container( 
                          decoration: BoxDecoration( 
                            image: const DecorationImage( image: NetworkImage("..."), ), 
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0) 
                          ), 
                        ), 
                        const Text("Pineapple") 
                      ],
                    ) 
                  ],
                ) 
              ], 
            ), 
          ) 
        ], 
      ) 
    )
  );
}
```